# Errno 13 Permission denied when reading large text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I am reading data from a large text file using `file.readline()`. In the beginning the file is read correctly until a specific line (every time I run this code, it stops at this line). The process will be end then report this error:

```
File "E:/Det_devided_2/analysis.py", line 286, in <module>
  caculate_neg(path, 429496730, part_id)
File "E:/Det_devided_2/analysis.py", line 229, in caculate_neg
  det_line = file.readline() 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

P.S.
The text file is in an mobile hard disk.

Comment: It means your script does not have the privileges to read the file or access the device (and probably has nothing to do with the file's size — something you could easily check).

Comment: run the script as a superuser

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try them as soon as I can. But, what is strange is that, the text file was read successfully in the beginning, then after reading like 800000 lines, this error occurs. If I do not have the permission, shouldn't it fail in the beginning?

Comment: Yes, it would have failed from the get-go.

Answer (score 1):

`PermsionDenied` errors are usually the result of the appropriate permissions not being available to the user such as reading/writing protected files.

---

**On Windows:**

1. Open the cmd(or Powershell) as an administrator :
   [image: Run cmd as administrator]
2. Run :`python <yourscript>.py`
   [image: Run python script]

---

**on Linux:**

You can run an individual command as an administrator using `sudo` grated you have permission to use `sudo` by the administrator

`sudo python <yourscript>.py`

---

---

**Other possibilities:**

A permission denied error on an external device can also be because of faulty device or the device could be encrypted

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! Running in CMD solved the problem.

Comment: @KKK.Price No problem, I am happy it helped :)

Comment:  Then the error occurs again around 70000000th line. This is so strange.

Comment: Did you run it as an Admin

Comment: Are you perhaps using an external hard drive or flashdrive

Comment: We found out that the hard drive is broken. 

Comment: I have included that as a possible reason in my answer for documentation purposses

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work